# Why does my WordPress Upgrade version have a language suffix?

Tags: localization

In My WordPress dashboard at `update-core.php`, it says:

> An updated version of WordPress is available.
>
> You can update to WordPress 5.3–en_GB automatically:
>
> [Upgrade button]
>
> (This localised version contains both the translation and various other localisation fixes. You can skip upgrading if you want to keep your current translation.)
>
> You can update to WordPress 5.3–en_US automatically:
>
> [Upgrade button]

Why does my WordPress installation show this localised version upgrade? and how can I turn it off?

Comment: Is this a problem?

Comment: No, It's not a problem. I would say it is a very minor usability smell. We wanted to upgrade WordPress but we didn't know which Upgrade button to click. I wanted to make it easier next time, so I wanted to disable the localization so there is only one upgrade button. Now I know how. I posted the question to help others in the same situation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the General Settings page there is a "*Site Language*" option - if you select "English (United States)" and Save Changes, the localised version upgrade option will disappear. Selecting any other Language option will localise WordPress.

[image]